# How do I deal with projects with multiple files sing Vim-latex

Tags: vim-latex

So I started a big project which has multiple files that are `includ`ed in the main file. I'm using `vim`, specifically with the `vim-latex` plugin.

The problem is that `vim-latex` doesn't work for the standalone .tex files (because they lack a preamble). And by that I mean that the shortcuts don't work (like the F9 autocompletion, F5, etc; I don't really care that much about the compilation commands). How to I deal with this?

I did some research and it seems to me that one of the solutions is to use a `main.tex.latexmain` file. Maybe I'm missing something obvious but I'm not sure what goes in that file. According to the [docs](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project-settings.html) it should be Vim commands, but I honestly have no idea which commands and I couldn't find one single example online.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "vim-latex doesn't work for standalone files"? Are you unable to edit them? Or do you want to compile the main file while you are editing a standalone file? Or do you want to compile the standalone file without compiling the main file?

Comment: @Marijn I mean the shortcuts don't work. Sorry I should have specified better. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like vim is detecting the incorrect file type. A blank `.tex` document will have the vim file type `plaintex`, where as a LaTeX document has file type `tex`. It would appear that `vim-latex` does not run on `plaintex`. There are at least two ways to force vim to read it as a `tex` file type:

1. Add the following line at the top of the tex file to change the file type detected by vim:

```
% vim: set filetype=tex :
```

2. Add an auto command to your `.vimrc` file to make `vim-latex` run in all `.tex` files:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex set filetype=tex
```